# How to generate authorization URL for OAuth 2.0 consent screen in .Net Core Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-oauth, console-application

I know that it is possible to generate OAuth2.0 consent screen URL within a .net framework via deprecated Google.GData.Client library in a **bare Console Application**. The flow looks like following:

```
// OAuth2Parameters object, which holds all the parameters related to OAuth 2.0.
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();

// Set OAuth 2.0 Client Id
parameters.ClientId = clientId;

// Set  OAuth 2.0 Client Secret
parameters.ClientSecret = clientSecret;

// Set Redirect URI (in this case it will return authorization code in browser)
parameters.RedirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

// Set Desired Scope.
parameters.Scope = scope;

// desired URL via OAuthUtil's static method
string url = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters);
```

This URL I could open in browser, view Google consent screen, click allow and retrieve authorization code, which I then would use to get appropriate access and refresh tokens
like this:

```
parameters.AccessCode = Console.ReadLine();
OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters);
accessToken = parameters.AccessToken;
refreshToken = parameters.RefreshToken;
```

My major problem is that I would like to do this in a **bare .Net Core Console Application** (without GData ofcourse), but I struggle to find how. I guess, it is possible to do this in general, at least [there are](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) active examples for PHP, Ruby and Python for doing something very similar for
calling YouTube API. Can somebody possibly know, how to do this in .Net Core?

Also, this can't be handled with service account (I don't have problem with that in my app) as users might not be from my organization, so looks like viewing consent screen is necessary.

Comment: Which library exactly are you using. Google has been in the process of shutting down all the GData apis for the last eight or ten years.  Why would you use that?

Comment: @DaImTo, I do not use GData, I simply know it was possible to do so with it. The point is, I would like to do something similar with a possible analogy of GData, which is not deprecated and available in .net core.

Comment: I cant even find the Github project for the GData library for .Net, I remember pinging someone at google about having it moved from Google code and im sure it was moved i just cant find the library anymore.    My guess is they have removed it, the last API that was activly using it was the Google sheets v2 which they shut down last year.   Move to the Google .net client library and forget about the Gdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Oauth2 flow.

Oauth2 is actually easy enough to handle you just need to be able to do HTTP GET and HTTP Post calls.

The first thing we do is create the link that will cause the consent screen to appear. This is a HTTP Get call so can be placed in any web browser.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&response_type=code
```

When the user consents to access the authorization code will be displayed to them on the page.

The next thing you will need to do is exchange that authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

This is a HTTP POST call, you can do it with .net core easy enouhg here is an example of the call using Curl

```
curl -s \
--request POST \
--data "code=4/1AY0e-g7BhBt0QU9f5HTgNDGNR1GYtH12q4xvgL_D2Q34A&client_id=XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=zYAoXDam3mqsdwabh3dQ3NTh&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

At which point the server will return to you an access token

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.a0AfH6SMDypscIeiyNnPRvoizz3NvvA6SZdk9U4K8h4MyQRRm29kEc2shdrskPZp71Q1roy8RqIm_7spufW84ozUoSTk0QKkQ",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "1//09Y5LQ0XRxjt-CgYIARAAGAkSNwF-L9IrYzyMnbGtJHgh-FTf6z79cBhQ1hsPUAk71HFgFwqyXoiwpIa-4eA",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

If you would like to know how it all works I have a video here [Understanding Oauth2 with curl](https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w) companion blog post [How to get a Google access token with CURL](https://www.daimto.com/how-to-get-a-google-access-token-with-curl/)

## google .net client library

I strongly sujest that you use the [Google .net clinet library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet)  supports .net core.

The following is an example of authorization with an installed application  (console application).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// ** Installed Application only ** 
    /// This method requests Authentcation from a user using Oauth2.  
    /// Credentials are stored in System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
    /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientSecretJson">Path to the client secret json file from Google Developers console.</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Identifying string for the user who is being authentcated.</param>
    /// <param name="scopes">Array of Google scopes</param>
    /// <returns>authencated UserCredential</returns>
    private static UserCredential GetUserCredential(string clientSecretJson, string userName, string[] scopes)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("userName");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientSecretJson))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("clientSecretJson");
            if (!File.Exists(clientSecretJson))
                throw new Exception("clientSecretJson file does not exist.");

            // These are the scopes of permissions you need. It is best to request only what you need and not all of them               
            using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretJson, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);

                // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored authentication for userName
                var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                         scopes,
                                                                         userName,
                                                                         CancellationToken.None,
                                                                         new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

                credential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
                return credential;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Get user credentials failed.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Both my website [Daimto.com](http://daimto.com) and my YouTube channel [Daimto developer tips](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyqzvMN8newXIxyYIkFzPvA) Have examples for using the google apis with .net.  I also have a github project [Google-Dotnet-Samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples) with examples for most of the apis.

Comment: This is not exactly, what i want to do. I would like to generate a URL for a consent screen, which users will open in their browsers, log in to their Google Accounts (if not already), view list of consents, click apply and view authorization code, which they have to input inside application console to proceed using my app.

Comment: So you want to do this manually yourself?  without the library?    Give me a sec.

Comment: @DaImTo I don't think he means without the library. In python library there's InstalledAppFlow class and it has method `run_console` : https://google-auth-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.html#InstalledAppFlow.run_console  . Is there same in .NET library?

Comment: @cikatomo the author is not using python the author is using C# not sure i understand your point?  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is for installed apps for example running as a console app.   It should automatically open the browser for them.

Comment: he wants to do the same with C# library that's the point. AuthorizeSync as opens browser but it doesn't show code you can copy paste into the console terminal, but it redirects to localhost which doesn't work. If you know how to do it then say it , with code, that's the question

Comment: I believe what you are talking about is [OAuth out-of-band (oob) flow will be deprecated](https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html#dates-oob)  Yes there is a method to retrieve the consent form url from the library but again that is [deprecated](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/commit/c58dbd5d32188f26035d7491aa2968b348707799). Do you think its wise to add deprecated methods in answers.